# Profit from biomass gasification patent

Tags: ca2827105a1

The inventors are named and the organization is a non profit. who will eventually profit from this patent if it is granted?

Answer (score 1):

The organization could sell the patent, license it, or otherwise collect revenue from it.

Being a non-profit doesn't mean they can't make money, it means that the company uses surplus revenues to achieve its goals rather than distributing them as profit or dividends.

The Denver Zoological Foundation can quite happily make money from this patent, if and when it issues: http://www.google.com/patents/CA2827105A1?cl=en